# Unable to get search results for number field in SharePoint Online list

Tags: sharepoint-online

We have a SharePoint Online list where we have a few number type columns created. When we try to search for values in any of the number type fields, there are no search results. Whereas when we search for values in any other field type (like single line text, choice, boolean etc) the results are coming correctly.
Upon searching more on this, we found that there are no crawled properties created for the number type fields due to which these fields are not searcheable.
We did re-indexing on the list and on the site as well. But still the crawled propoerties are not showing up for number fields (other fields has crawled properties created).
Can anyone help me on how we can make the crawled properties created for the number fields?

Comment: Is it a site column or a list column (have you created it directly from list settings)??

Comment: SharePoint only generates searchable fields automatically for Site Columns.  If you created the column directly on the List, you will need to go the Search Schema in SharePoint Admin Center and manually create Searchable Properties.

Comment: It is a list column. But all other fields which are searcheable currently in that list are also list columns and not site columns. But I will anyway try to create a site column for number fields and check if they can be searched,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the crawled property is from a number/currency column, you need to map it to a searchable managed property in order to get full text index recall.

Here is an article about “what makes a SharePoint column searchable” for your reference:

https://www.techmikael.com/2014/07/what-makes-sharepoint-column-searchable.html

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked for me.